# Rails 4: how to include selected association in searching/filtering a model entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

First of all, I am totally new to Rails and still on the steep learning curve. I recently took over a rails project and need to do some tweaking on the existing code.

I need to include an association named '`School`' when searching/filtering the model named '`Teacher`'. A teacher `has_many` schools.

In the search method of the teacher controller, I have the following:

```
def search
if params[:id].present? || params[:city].present?
  @teachers = Teacher.include(:schools).all
  @teachers = @teachers.matches('id', params[:id]) if params[:id].present?
  @teachers = @teachers.matches('name', params[:city]) if params[:city].present?
else
   @teachers = []
end
end
```

However, the `.include(:schools)` does not work for me. I also tried to use `.eager_loading(:schools)`, but does not work either.

Comment: It should be `includes(:schools)` not sure if that was just a typo.  What is in your models?

Comment: yes, that was a typo. Thank you

Comment: Can you describe what exactly isn't working? Is there an error, or does it just fail to eager load?

Comment: Yup need more details on 'does not work'. Do you get errors in the rails console? In the browser? Or just wrong results? What is the SQL the console is logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
def search
  if params[:id].present? || params[:city].present?
    @teachers = Teacher.includes(:schools)
    if params[:id].present?
      @teachers = @teachers.find params[:id]
    elsif params[:city].present?
      @teachers = @teachers.find_by_name params[:city]
    end
  else
     @teachers = []
  end
end
```

I think you are using `include` instead of `includes`. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. I also found it necessary to modify the json template in the view directory. Appreciate it